# No module flow.controllers Aimsun/Flow-project

Tags: flow-project

I can't run any of the flow-project examples for aimsun, even though I have followed all the installation steps.  The error I get for the sugiyama example is `No module named flow.controllers` and `No module flow.core.experiment` for the small_template one. I have the flow environment activated whilst trying to run the scripts. Any idea why I get these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will be fixed in the next versions of Flow. You have couple of options: 
1 - You can change directory to Flow directory (`path/to/flow`) and run examples from there like `python examples/aimsun/sugiyama.py`.
2 - You can add the path to Flow directory to PYTHONPATH. You can run `export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/flow"` and then run the examples. You can also add this command to `~/.bashrc`.